# Checking for Number / NaN type with switch-case

Tags: javascript

```js
function timeAdder(value) {
  switch (value) {
    case Number:
      console.log("its a number");
      break;

    case isNaN:
      console.log("its not a number");
      break;

    default:
      console.log("erroe");
      break;

  }
}

timeAdder("a")
```

Comment: Was there any particular reason you wanted to use `switch` for this? It looks like you only really want to check whether a value was a number or not.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below.Use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator to check the type of the variable

```js
function timeAdder(value) {
  switch (typeof value) {
    case "number":
      console.log("its a number");
      break;

    case "string":
      console.log("its not a number");
      break;

    default:
      console.log("erroe");
      break;

  }
}

timeAdder("a")
timeAdder(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `type of`

```js
function timeAdder(value) {
  switch (typeof value) {
    case 'number':
      console.log("its a number");
      break;

    case 'string':
      console.log("its not a number, it is string");
      break;

    default:
      console.log("erroe");
      break;

  }
}

timeAdder("A")
timeAdder(1)
```